# Circuits for electric storage heating

Tags: electrical, heating, uk, electric-heat

I have been looking at some flats in UK (apartments) which have electric storage heating.

One flat has very old storage units, with two power supplies: one for the night (economy) rate, and one for the day rate. This I understand. The night circuit is independantly controlled by a sealed time switch, so that it will only supply power within the night time period.

Another flat has modern Gabarron ECOHHR30 storage units, with only one power supply.

Am I right in thinking that the supply is automatically switched between the day and night circuits at the consumer unit?

Comment: It would depend on whether you have a smart meter.

Comment: @Chenmunka I was told by the previous resident they could not have a smart meter, because it is Economy 7.

Comment: Economy 7 used to run off a separate meter. It is years since I used it so my knowledge is a bit out of date.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think there probably are two meters. I am wondering why there is only one cable to the heater unit. (There does not seem to be any point having storage heating, if there isn't a cheap tariff to run them from.) The heater does have timer settings, and the simple answer could be that a modern consumer unit would switch the power source for the circuit. I've tried googling that, but can't find a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found an answer on one page of the heater manufacturer's [website](https://www.elnur.co.uk/news/single-supply-storage-heaters-what-is-required/), by googling, that I could not find through its own menus.

> **Replacing a standard storage heater for a Elnur ECOHHR or Elnur ECOSSH and using a single supply.**
>
> 1. There must be a single meter installed and the householder must be on an “unrestricted” E7 or E10 tariff variant from their energy provider, which allows the whole house supply to operate 24/7 and charge the off peak tariff price for all consumption during the off-peak period(s) and the higher tariff price during all other hours.
> 2. With the correct meter installed and tariff in use, wiring changes can be done at the heating consumer unit or split load consumer unit where the storage heaters are connected. The supply to the storage heaters side of the consumer unit can now be changed to the same household supply. No timers or contactors are needed when supplying the heaters as all timings will be controlled at the storage heaters.
>
> Note: It is important that the timing of the off peak period matches the timing set on the heaters otherwise running costs will be higher.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do time-of-day tariffs.

I suspect that the UK has been doing the same thing the US has, which is making a shift from "multiple electric meters for special services" to "time of day metering".

The enabling technology here is the "smart meter". Classic meters required a human to visit a meter monthly and note numbers off the readout, giving only "monthly" granularity as to energy use. Smart meters give 15- or 30-minute granularity, and they report data back via powerline signaling, so now there is no need for a second meter.

The power company simply charges you one rate during the day and another rate during the evening. As regards storage heaters, you are expected to serve your own financial self-interest and program them to charge up at night.

The reason for the rate change is grid provisioning. The total grid demand varies hour by hour and day by day, and they're trying to incentivize load-shifting away from peak hours, because otherwise they're building a lot of peaking generators that only run a few hours a year.

In the US there is strong popular insistence on a flat rate tariff as a default, but offer optional time-of-use tariffs, including "market following" tariffs like the one documented here.

https://youtu.be/0f9GpMWdvWI?t=322

And if your home is well-insulated, you *might want* to review the rest of that video (minding that Americans reverse things and use electricity for A/C instead of heat, but that's not important). Those storage heaters use "hot rocks" of some kind to store heat; Alec replaces the hot rocks *with the thermal mass of the whole house*.  By Alec's math, that large American suburban house stores about 16 KWH.  So *at least* 5 KWH could happen for you if the insulation is tight.

Comment: I haven't digested all of this yet. But in one former residence with off-peak electric storage heating, as described in the question, I had cavity wall insulation installed. The inner skin was brick (not any kind of cement block) with a high thermal mass, and after that the entire house acted a bit like a thermos flask. The inner brickwork skin gave thermal stability and ensured that the house had more-or-less constant temperature 24/7. I'm unsure of the relevance of US practices.

Comment: Although you say that the smart meter is the enabling technology, in a brief convo with the present resident I was told they could not have a smart meter because of the dual tariff. Yet one electricity supplier I read said that you can. Perhaps it's a symptom of heating technolgy evolving rapidly, and not everything is equal. Some didn't, some do, some don't.

Comment: Nobody "forces variable tariffs onto you" in UK. We are entirely free to operate on the regular tariff if we choose to. If a cheap tariff is available, we can choose to take advantage of it by installing off-peak storage heating.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK I removed that... I had heard that from Alec (that video) who is usually picayune about getting details right.  The only reason I mentioned the US experience is to frame a context for Alex's video.  I hope that didn't offend.